# C# Create Tracks Parents which Depend on Children

Tags: c#, sql-server, listbox, parent-child

I'm trying to create tracks of Parent that have more than a child and put theme in dynamic ListBox

i have this ParentActivity table"

[tblParentActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbnrC.jpg)

and I want to make tracks depend on ParentActivity table to be in ListBox like this:

[Tracks in ListBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF5Um.jpg)

the code so far:

```
private void TrackingActivity(long ParentActivityID)
{

    DataTable dtActiveChild = objA.SelectActivityChild(ParentActivityID);

        ListBox lstBox = new ListBox();
        lstBox.ID = "lstTrack" + ParentActivityID.ToString();
        lstBox.Width = 200;
        pnlTrack.Controls.Add(lstBox);

        for (int i = 0; i < dtActiveChild.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            long ActivityChildID =  Convert.ToInt64(dtActiveChild.Rows[i]["ActivityID"].ToString());
            string ActivityChildName = dtActiveChild.Rows[i]["ActivityName"].ToString();

            lstBox.Items.Add(new ListItem (ActivityChildName.ToString(),ActivityChildID.ToString()));

            DataTable dtBrotherActivity = objA.selectBrotherActivity(ActivityChildID);

            if (dtBrotherActivity.Rows.Count > 0)
            {              
                TrackingActivity(ActivityChildID);
            }
        } 
}
```

for example ParentActivityID=1;

selectBrotherActivity is query to get another child of it parent

it gave me distribution like this:

|1|2 3|4 5|7|9|10|7|9|10|6|8|9|10|

which || means ListBox

Comment: What code do you have so far, and what are you stuck on?

Comment: Do you need help with the C# code or the sql to pull this data out of that table? As posted this entirely too vague.

Comment: using c# to make track but if I can distribute track with sql it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to everyone I found it:

```
protected void btnCreateTrack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

  ListBox lstBoxParent = new ListBox();
  lstBoxParent.ID = "lstTrack1";
  lstBoxParent.Width = 200;
  lstBoxParent.Height = 200;
  pnlTrack.Controls.Add(lstBoxParent);

  TrackingActivity(1, lstBoxParent );

}



private void TrackingActivity(long ParentActivityID, ListBox lstBoxParent)
{

    chk:

    DataTable dtActiveChild  = objWFAI.SelectActivityChild(ParentActivityID);
    string ActivityName = objWFA.CurrentActivityName(ParentActivityID);


    lstBoxParent.Items.Add(new ListItem(ActivityName, ParentActivityID.ToString()));

    for (int i = dtActiveChild .Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        long ActivityChildID = Convert.ToInt64(dtActiveChild .Rows[i][" ActivityID"].ToString());

        if (i != 0)
        {
            ListBox lstBoxChild = new ListBox();
            lstBoxChild.ID = "lstTrack" + ActivityChildID.ToString();
            lstBoxChild.Width = 200;
            lstBoxChild.Height = 200;
            pnlTrack.Controls.Add(lstBoxChild);

            for (int p = 0; p < lstBoxParent.Items.Count; p++)
            {
                lstBoxChild.Items.Add(new ListItem(lstBoxParent.Items[p].Text, lstBoxParent.Items[p].Value));
            }
            TrackingActivity(ActivityChildID, lstBoxChild);
        }
        else
        {
            ParentActivityID = ActivityChildID ;

            goto chk;
        }
    }
```